# Save operation using ODataModel

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am new to SAP ui5. I have successfully shown data using ODataModel to a table. Now I want to update the data in the table back into the database.
For this I know that we have something called **'update'** function of the model in which we can specify the path and the data. My question here is what if I want to give the data in the form of **json**? How do I retrieve data in the table in the form of json and have it passed to the **'update'** method?

Any help would be appreciated. If possible please share example such.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OData model object to get it. Use the path to retrieve the JSON object, update what you need, and then call the `update` function. Here's an example:

```
getDataContext : function(oItem) {
  var sPath = oItem.getBindingContextPath();
  var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
  return {
    path : sPath,
    data : oModel.getObject(sPath)
  };
}
```

From there you can update the data in `mDataContext.data` as desired, then call the update:

```
this.getView().getModel().update(
  mDataContext.path,
  mDataContext.data,
  { // your context, success, error handlers etc }
)
```

Here's a [fully working example](http://jsbin.com/polis/3/edit?html,js,output) that allows you to look at products in Northwind, select one, and increase or decrease that selected product's rating.